# How do I query an Id in an array? Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I query a specific _id in an array using mongoose

Here's the code

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   resume: {
      educations: [{
          school: String,
          year: String
      }]
   }
});
```

How do I specifically query a educations id?

My attempt

```
User.findById({ 'resume.educations._id': req.body.education_id}, function(err, foundUser){

   console.log(foundUser) --> Keep returning Undefined
});
```

The data that has been stored

[image]

`console.log(req.body.education_id)` --> `5644318364acb9f1eb25c939`

Comment: It's called `educations` not `education`.

Comment: Sorry, probably typo, but still it shows undefined.

Comment: `console.log` the error. See if you get any error.

Comment: It's definately a typo. Also you need to check basic things such as is `_id` actually present in the data ( it won't be if not created by mongoose ) and that you are actually passing something into your query that actually matches.

Comment: @IonicăBizău the user does exist, but its just my querying method most probably doesn't work

Comment: @BlakesSeven yeah, the _id in the educations has been generated because I already created the data, but I'm searching the correct method to query the specific educations fields

Comment: Edit your question to show the document you expect to match. Add some console logging to test the `req.body.education_id` parameter that you are passing in and supply that as well. A `null` result means nothing is matched, so there is something either wrong with your inputs or the document itself.

Comment: @BlakesSeven check the edited question, I added some data

Comment: Now can you see it's `req.body._id` and not `req.body.education_id`?

Comment: @BlackSeven Its just typo, forgot to add education, changed it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*$elementMatch*](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) with findOne like so

```
User.findOne({'resume.educations': {$elemMatch: {_id: '564497eb366f59b004e9d17e'}}}, function(err, foundUser){

   console.log(foundUser);
   // output
   // [ { resume: { educations: [ [Object] ] },
   //   __v: 0,
   //   _id: 564497eb366f59b004e9d17d } ]

});
```

this is a document i tried it on and it worked

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("564497eb366f59b004e9d17d"),
        "resume" : {
                "educations" : [
                        {
                                "school" : "school name",
                                "year" : "1999",
                                "_id" : ObjectId("564497eb366f59b004e9d17e")
                        }
                ]
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```